# Is there anyway for only one account on my PS4 to have PS Plus and not the others?

Tags: ps4

Let's just I say I want only my account to have PS Plus exclusively - no other account can access multiplayer etc.

Is there anyway to do this, and is it reversible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Deactivate your console as the primary. When you log in with your account you'll be the only person who can use the features you own. Any other accounts on the console will need the appropriate subscriptions to play online if it's required. To change it make your console your primary and everybody can use your stuff.